# mvc ajax dropdownlist value problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, model-view-controller

So I'm having problems with dealing with cascading dropdownlists. Everytime I would pick a value on the 1st dropdown the 2nd dropdown will be populated but "with the selected value from the first" at the top of the 2nd dropdown.  Does that make sense? Following are the codes. I'm not sure if it's appending correctly, can't seem to find anything on firebug.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!!

the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("1stLevel") %>').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%: Url.Action("Index","2ndLevelDetails") %>?1stLevelId=' + $(this).val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("2ndLevelId") %>').html(data);
                },
                async: false
            });
        });
    });
</script>


            <div class="dropdown">
                <%: Html.DropDownList("1stLevelDetails", new SelectList(Model.1stLevel, "1stLevelId", "1stLevelDescription"))%>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.2ndLevelId, new SelectList(Model.NTEESecondaryCodes, "2ndLevelId", "2ndLevelDescription", Model.2ndLevelId))%>
            </div>
```

the controller 2ndlevel that returns the list of options

```
public string Index(int 1stLevelId)
{
    var ntee = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (2ndLevelDetails code in 2ndLevelDetails.Find2ndLevelIds(ArgentDb, 1stLevelId))
    {
        ntee.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">{1}</option>", code.2ndLevelId, code.Description);
    }

    return ntee.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the 'change' event is valid & firing? Change the Ajax code to a simple alert to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery's live binder ..

```
$('#<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("1stLevel") %>').live('change', function () {
// ... code here
```

I've had to use live to bind to the change event since I can remember.. I don't know why.